# For a given certain situation how to prove that the system will never get into the state of Deadlock

Tags: operating-systems, concurrency, deadlocks

The situation is as follows

> 'm' process shares 'n' resources of same type. The maximum need of
>   each process does not exceed 'n' and the sum all their maximum needs
>   is always less than m+n. In this set up will deadlock ever occur

This is a question from **Operating System Concepts** by **Silberschatz, Gagne and Galvin**.

I tried to prove this using using *Banker's Algorithm*. Initially, I assumed that the *Allocated Matrix* for 'm' processes is a zero matrix. And *Maximum Matrix* of 'm' process is 'n'. Since *Need matrix* is difference of *Allocated Matrix* and *Max Matrix* therefore, *Need Martix* is equilavent of *Maximum Matrix*. And at last *Available Matrix* is equal to 'n'.

At this point I feel stuck and not able to find a way to proceed. Looking forward for help from you guys.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint: Petri nets!

Comment: @Raphael Is Petri Nets similar to resource allocation graph? Or they are two different concept.

Comment: I can't answer that in a comment. Google "Petri net", it's a famous formalism. You'll find lots of material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of a related problem helped me in the proof. Here I am first sharing that question along with one of the possible answer, and later propose my proof in a similar manner.

> Consider a system which has $3$ processes and each process requires $2$ identical resources to complete their execution then what is the minimum number of resources required to ensure deadlock free execution.

The easy way to do this is, *allocate exactly one less than the required number of instances of the resource to all the processes. Except for one of the processes, whose need is completely fulfilled*.

If there are $3$ processes say $P_1,P_2,P_3$. We give exactly one instance of the resource to $P_2, P_3$ and two instances of resource to $P_1$. In total $4$ instances of the resource are required to ensure a deadlock free execution.

Let us now generalize this concept and see what we get.

---

There are $m$ processes say $P_1,P_2,P_3,..,P_m$ sharing $n$ resources. And let $S_i$ be the maximum requirement of a process $P_i$ to execute completely.

Now to ensure that system is deadlock-free, we ***allocate all the processes exactly one less than the required number of instances of the resource except for one of the processes whose requirement is completely fulfilled***.

Mathematically,

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}S_i-m+1 \leq n$$

or we can say

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}S_i < m+n$$

This expression tells us that as long as the sum of maximum need of all the processes is less than $m+n$, the system will remain deadlock free.

HTH

Answer (score 3):

The question in the given situation is equivalent to the question: is it possible to create or to design a system such that m processes sharing n resources of the same type may enter a deadlock state subject to the following: each process needs less than or equal to n resources, and the total number of needed resources is less than or equal to m+n (“For a given certain situation”, 2015)?

Assumptions. Processes run on a single processor. The processor can execute a statement from one and only one process at a time. In other words every statement in a process is an atomic operation. After ending a statement and before executing the next statement of a process, the processor can switch to another process and execute the other process’ next statement.

Consider using a Petri Net for the system design. In terms of Petri Nets a deadlock is a situation when no transition is enabled. Figure 1 is an example of a system that may enter a deadlock state. In this example, m=2 and n=2.
For the same number of processes and resource needs per process (m=2 and n=2), it is also possible to create a system that does not enter a deadlock state. Each of Figure 2 and Figure 3 is an example of two systems that will never reach a deadlock state.

Figure 1: A System with Deadlock
[image: A System with Deadlock]

Figure 2: A System without Deadlock
[image: A System without Deadlock]

Figure 3: Another System without Deadlock
[image: Another System without Deadlock]

### Notes

For Figure 1, the transitions related to Process 1 (Process 2) are:

- T0 (T4) – get 1 resource unit.
- T1 (T5) – get 1 resource unit.
- T2 (T6) – process critical section.
- T3 (T7) – return 2 resource units.

For Figure 2, the transitions related to Process 1 (Process 2) are:

- T0 (T4) – get 1 resource unit.
- T1 (T5) – get 1 resource unit.
- T2 (T6) – process critical section.
- T3 (T7) – return 2 resource units.
- T8 (T9) – return 1 resource unit.

For Figure 3, the transitions related to Process 1 (Process 2) are:

- T0 (T3) – get 2 resource units.
- T1 (T4) – process critical section.
- T2 (T5) – return 2 resource units.

[For the PDF version of this reply](http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/OnMWQ1449933168.pdf), Figure 1, Figure 2 and Figure 3 are interactive, dynamic diagrams.

### References

Chionglo, J. F (2015). "A Reply to "For a given certain situation how to prove that the system will never get into the state of deadlock" at Computer Science Stack Exchange". Available at http://www.aespen.ca/AEnswers/OnMWQ1449933168.pdf

“For a given certain situation how to prove that the system will never get into the state of Deadlock” (2015). Mathematics Stack Exchange. Retrieved on Dec. 2, 2015 at [For a given certain situation how to prove that the system will never get into the state of Deadlock](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44030/for-a-given-certain-situation-how-to-prove-that-the-system-will-never-get-into-t).